# Taking union of two lists of IEnumerable and IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Hi I have two tables tabl1 and table2. I am trying search the each table for certain date once i get lists c1 and c2 then I need to get union of the two, so I have one distinct list with no repeating rows using entity framework.

```
  ssEntities sss = new ssEntities();
  var c1 = sss.table1.ToList().Where(x => x.date >= DateTime.Today);
  var c2=sss.table2.ToList().Where(x=>x.date1 DateTime.Today);
  var ll=c1.Union(c2).ToList();
```

When I try to take union of the two lists I get error given below

```
Instance argument: cannot convert from 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<testproject.table1>' to   'System.Linq.IQueryable<testproject.table2>'
```

Please help.

Comment: Are `table1` and `table2` different types?  If so you cannot union two `IEnumerable` of different types.  Instead, `ll` must contain objects of either the type of `table1`, the type of `table2` or another type of your choosing.

Comment: Project it into an anonymous class, or into a common class for both of hem

Comment: Why call ToList() on table1 and table2 right away?  You are putting the entire contents of the table in memory before you filter by date.  You might as well let the db server do that filtering for you.

Answer (score 3):

That's easy enough

```
ssEntities sss = new ssEntities();
  var c1 = sss.table1.ToList().Where(x => x.date >= DateTime.Today)
                            .Select(x => new { x.Prop1, x.Prop2 });
  var c2 = sss.table2.ToList().Where(x => x.date1 >= DateTime.Today)
                            .Select(x => new { x.Prop1, x.Prop2 });
  var ll = c1.Union(c2).ToList();
```

You have to only select the properties you want from each table , and they have to be the same, so that the union will work, you can't do a Union on 2 different types.